# Why do I have to import this from numpy if I am just referencing it from the numpy module

Tags: python, numpy

Aloha!

I have two blocks of code, one that will work and one that will not.  The only difference is a commented line of code for a numpy module I don't use.  Why am I required to import that model when I never reference "npm"?

This command works:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.matlib as npm

V  = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
P1 = np.matlib.identity(V.shape[1], dtype=int)
P1
```

This command doesn't work:

```
import numpy as np
#import numpy.matlib as npm

V  = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
P1 = np.matlib.identity(V.shape[1], dtype=int)
P1
```

The above gets this error:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'matlib'
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"This command doesn't work"* Is not a valid problem statement. **How** does it not work? Does it give incorrect results? Does it given an exception? Error message exist for a reason: to give you clues as to why there was an error. If you exclude them, you just wasted the programmer's time who carefully wrote that error message, as well as ours.

Comment: Sure thing, here is the error message:

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9e3582dc84df> in <module>()
      3 
      4 V  = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])
----> 5 P1 = np.matlib.identity(V.shape[1], dtype=int)
      6 P1

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'matlib'

Comment: This is a common idiom. Packages don't import optional sub-packages by default. You have to do it before using it.

Comment: but you do reference `np.matlib`, just not using the alias `npm` (which is optional)

Comment: The comments about sub packages helped me understand why I was getting the error.  Thanks!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### Short Answer

This is because `numpy.matlib` is an optional sub-package of `numpy` that must be imported separately.

The reason for this feature may be:

- In particular for `numpy`, the `numpy.matlib` sub-module redefines `numpy`'s functions to return matrices instead of ndarrays, an optional feature that many may not want
- More generally, to load the parent module without loading a potentially slow-to-load module which many users may not often need
- Possibly, namespace separation

When you import just `numpy` without the sub-package `matlib`, then Python will  be looking for `.matlib` as an attribute of the `numpy` package. This attribute has not been assigned to `numpy` without importing `numpy.matlib` (see discussion below)

### Sub-Modules and Binding

If you're wondering why `np.matlib.identity` works without having to use the keyword `npm`, that's because when you import the sub-module `matlib`, the parent module `numpy` (named `np` in your case) will be given an attribute `matlib` which is bound to the sub-module. This only works if you first define `numpy`.

From the [reference](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/import.html#submodules):

> When a submodule is loaded using any mechanism (e.g. importlib APIs, the import or import-from statements, or built-in **import**()) a binding is placed in the parent module’s namespace to the submodule object.

### **Importing and __init__.py**

The choice of what to import is determined in the modules' respective `__init__.py` files in the module directory. You can use the `dir()` function to see what names the respective modules define.

```
>> import numpy

>> 'matlib' in dir(numpy)
# False

>> import numpy.matlib

>> 'matlib' in dir(numpy)
# True
```

Alternatively, if you look directly at the [`__init__.py` file for `numpy`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/__init__.py) you'll see there's no import for `matlib`.

### Namespace across Sub-Modules

If you're wondering how the namespace is copied over *smoothly*;

The [`matlib` source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/matlib.py) runs this command to copy over the `numpy` namespace:

```
import numpy as np                                    # (1)
...
# need * as we're copying the numpy namespace
from numpy import *                                   # (2)
...
__all__ = np.__all__[:] # copy numpy namespace        # (3)
```

Line (2), `from numpy import *` is particularly important. Because of this, you'll notice that if you just import `numpy.matlib` you can still use all of `numpy` modules without having to import `numpy`!

Without line (2), the namespace copy in line (3) would only be attached to the sub-module. Interestingly, you can still do a funny command like this because of line (3).

```
import numpy.matlib               
numpy.matlib.np.matlib.np.array([1,1])
```

This is because the `np.__all__` is attached to the `np` of `numpy.matlib` (which was imported via line (1)).

Comment: Edited: corrected a mistake I made on why you can use the functions `np.matlib.identity()` without having to use the `npm` name, and namespace stuff.

Answer (score 6):

You never use `npm` but you do use `np.matlib`, so you could change your 2nd import line to just:

```
import numpy.matlib
```

Or you could keep your 2nd import line as is but instead use:

```
P1 = npm.identity(V.shape[1], dtype=int)
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there are reason you don't use `np.identity`?

```
P1 = np.identity(V.shape[1], dtype=int)
```

> This module contains all functions in the numpy namespace, with the following replacement functions that return matrices instead of ndarrays.

Unless you are wedded to 2d `np.matrix` subclass, you are better off sticking with the regular `ndarray` versions.

(Others have pointed out that the import why is based on the `__init__` specs for `numpy`.  `numpy` imports most, but not all of its submodules.  The ones it does not automatically import are used less often.  It's a polite way of saying, `You don't really need this module`)

Comment: You're right, I should use that and am now.  Just wondered why it had an error in the first place. Thanks the comment!