# AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'matlib'

Tags: python, numpy, module

I recently started coding in Python. In the beginning of my scripts I always have the following import: `import numpy as np`.

In one of my scripts, I use `np.matlib.repmat` function. It used to work ok, however recently it fails to run showing the following error:

```
 AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'matlib'
```

I searched SO for this problem, and it looks like the error like this arises if one has a script called numpy.py in his working directory or if the installed version is different and does not contain the called module.

I didn't name any file numpy.py. I also found out that after I call:

```
 from numpy import matlib as mb
```

I can use `mb.repmat`. Therefore, my numpy module does contain `matlib` module.
Can someone hint me, why I cannot call `np.matlib`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This was already answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41818379/why-do-i-have-to-import-this-from-numpy-if-i-am-just-referencing-it-from-the-num/41818451).

> This is because `numpy.matlib` is an optional sub-package of `numpy`
>   that must be imported separately. When you import just `numpy` without
>   the sub-package `matlib`, then Python will be looking for `.matlib` as an
>   attribute of the `numpy` package. This attribute has not been assigned
>   to `numpy` without importing numpy.matlib

Comment: Gotcha! I'll close my question. Didn't find this answer. Thanks

Comment: If it's already answered in such detail as the link you shared, you should flag as a duplicate.

Comment: Just done that, I found out how to do it after posting, sorry